# Deleted almost everything from MacBook Air (2014) and still no storage?

Tags: storage, startup, disk-space, adobe-photoshop

Last night, I was working on Photoshop and it said my scratch disc was full which, after looking it up, meant my startup disc was full. I went through and deleted a good 95% of my photos, all the apps I never use that MacBook doesn't deem necessary (because Chess is very necessary), a lot of my documents, etc., etc., etc. After that, PhotoShop worked for me.

I was working on it again today, and it said my startup disc is almost full once again? Hardly anything has changed last night. What does this mean/what do I do?

Comment: Hi emauma - could you please try reinstalling macOS? [[directions here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)] This should clear your computer drive caches and fix up everything. **You will not lose any data, but macOS apps you deleted will be reinstalled.** Please reply to this comment if this works.

Comment: Hi Jackson1442, I think it worked! I've only retried what I was doing a few times, but there's been no trouble yet. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

### Reinstall macOS

It looks like cached system files are what's causing your storage problem. Reinstalling macOS **will not delete any personal information or files,** but resets all system files and restored deleted system apps.

[here's what Apple says about reinstalling macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904). I've reformatted the directions below to make your life easier:

Start by pressing the appropriate key combination for what you need. I suggest Command-R:
[image: table]

Now, using macOS utilities, select Reinstall macOS:

[image: macOS Utilities]]

Simply wait until the download and install is complete and your cached files should be cleared, solving your problem.